# Работа с расширяющимися объектами Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Не знаю, насколько точно сформировал название, но суть такая.

Есть сайт, на котором для отображения листа популярных постов достаточно следующей инфы:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "smallPost")
public class SmallPost {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "postId", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private long postId;

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "postId", nullable = false)
    private PostImage postImage;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "postId")
    private MiddlePost middlePost;

  //getters and setters
}
```

Он ссылается на его возможные изображения:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "postImage")
public class PostImage {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "postId", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private long postId;

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Column(name = "smallImg", nullable = false)
    private byte[] smallImg;

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(name = "middleImg")
    private byte[] middleImg;

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Column(name = "largeImg")
    private byte[] largeImg;

   //getters and setters
}
```

Дальше для поста, который просто будет отображаться в ленте добавляется картинка по больше, теги, изображения, просмотры.

А он ссылается еще на 1 таблицу, которая уже отображает полный пост, который остался.

И все эти @OneToOne связи с типом Lazy, т.е. они будут подгружаться только как я их запрошу, иначе для выведения маленького листа всех постов они потянут за собой всю инфу включая контент и изображения, которые их наполняют.

Но это означает, что когда мне потребуется получить последний левел поста, то моя ORM (Hibernate) сначала сделает запрос на получение среднего левела, потом сделает запрос на получение последнего левела, потом еще по запросу чтобы подгрузить необходимые листы для последнего левела + запрос чтобы получить последний размер картинки. В итоге вместо одного запроса с join'ами он сделает 10 запросов, чтобы получить последний уровень поста.

Это ведь точно так не делается, а как тогда можно в зависимости от запроса подгружать определенные данные из бд? Я не смог найти как это решить, буду рад любой помощи.

P.S. неплохо было бы если у кого-то есть ссылочки на более менее серьезные  Enterprise проекты на GitHub, чтобы можно было глянуть как там это реализуется.

Comment: Почему вас это волнует? Хибернейт сам знает, как ему вытаскивать, оставьте эту работу ему

Comment: @Roman Danilov, меня волнует то что я могу в sql написать 1 запрос с join и забыть про бд, не нагружать её, а тут hibernate сделает 3 запроса что неплохо понизит производительность приложения

Comment: Я думаю, вы не почувствуете никакой просадки. Вы же не highload приложение пишете